# Kibana - combine two columns to create a new column in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, kql

I am trying to make table using Kibana. What I have in mind is to create a column which for each instance, divides the corresponding values of two other columns.

The two base columns are created using Kibana's metrics. However I cannot find any option for merging two columns, or creating one from scratch what gets its data from two sources.

PS. I'm querying on logstach data.

Answer (score 1):

In KQL you can use [pack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction) or [strcat()](http://%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcatfunction) to achieve what you want (the former is probably a better option).